# Autoconvert/substring ZIP+4 into 5-digit ZIP Code

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I created a Group with ZIP Code as one of the attributes. Our ZIP codes are a mix bag of 5-digits and ZIP+4, e.g., 60004, 600046080, 608060004. I need to find all with first 5-digits 60004.

If I use "ZIP exist in: 60004", I will get all 3, which is incorrect.
If I use "ZIP exist in Whole Word: 60004", I will only get the first one, but not the second.

Neither is perfect. So I think I need to substring the first 5 characters as: 60004, 60004, 60806.

Do I need to create another attribute and manually export/substring/import?

Can I use SQL or Data Relationship to automate?

Comment: Don't quite know what you mean by group or where the attribute is? Do you mean a VisualForce component attribute? But if the data is stored in Salesforce and you need to do a SOQL call then you can use WHERE field LIKE '60004%'. Can you give me information...

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use ZIP **begins with**: 60004.

Comment: That works. However, if all zip codes are 5-digits only, I only need to write one if statement: "zipcode exists in whole word: 12345,23456,34567,… etc." without having to write one statement per zip code, which can be tedious.

ZIP begins with: only allow a single value, not a list of values. So I have to write:

ZIP begins with: 12345
ZIP begins with: 23456
ZIP begins with: 34567
… etc.